# SQL Server Containerization in Azure CLI

Tags: docker, containers, azure-cli

I would like to create a SQL Server container in Azure CLI with the following statement:

```
az container create --resource-group rgtest \gt; --name db_test > --image mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-CU16-ubuntu > --environment-variables ACCEPT_EULA=Y MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD= password_test > --dns-name-label dns_test > --cpu 2 > --memory 2 > --port 1433
```

I was expecting a JSON output that contains all the details and properties of container, but unfortunately, I am not getting anything returned. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I have removed the request for off-site resources, as such questions are off topic for Stack Overflow. As you haven't, I really suggest taking the [tour] and reading the [help], paying close attention to the articles on what you can and can't ask about here.

Answer (score 0):

There are some format mistakes in the command, you could use it like this:

```
az container create --resource-group rgtest --name dbtest --image mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-CU16-ubuntu  --environment-variables ACCEPT_EULA=Y MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=password_test  --dns-name-label dbtest  --cpu 2  --memory 2  --port 1433
```

[image]

More reference: [az container create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_container_create-examples)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Actually, for MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD, I had provided some special characters (symbols) to make it strong. Because of these special characters, the command was not working. Once I removed those, the command is working like a champ.

Comment: Could you show your full command to make it work? Or any screenshots are much better.